# Cakephp Complex Query buiding

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, mysqli, cakephp-2.8

I have three tables users, attributes and user_attributes.

```
users[id, name, username, password, dob, gender, isactive, registered_on],
attributes[id, name, isactive],
user_attributes[id, user_id, attribute_id]
```

This is my table structure with fields. Now I want to write a query which will fetch all the users from user table along with the value of user_attributes table if there any row exist in user_attributes table.

How to write the query in cakephp?
I have two Models `User` and `Attribute`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1-Create a Model UserAttribute for table user_attributes.

```
class UserAttribute extends AppModel{

}
```

2- In your User Model create hasMany association with UserAttribute

```
class User extends AppModel{

   public $hasMany = array(
            'UserAttribute' => array(
            'className' => 'UserAttribute',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',

            ),

     );

 }
```

3- Do find query in your controller:

```
$users= $this->User->find('all');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($users);
```

Comment: @VikashAmbani CakePHP supports automatic loading of associations, so using raw SQL queries if not explicitly required is not a good idea in most cases. The question is what the OP actually needs.